# Cannot find a parameter with this name:

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using jetpack compose to try to build a login, but I am getting the following error: Cannot find a parameter with this name: KeyboardType and Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor. Why is this error occurring?

I searched and reviewed the imports even the dependencies but I can't find the cause of this error. This is my function for the email field:

```
`fun EmailField() {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {},
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Email") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Email),
        singleLine = true,
        maxLines = 1,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            textColor = Color(0xFF636262),
            backgroundColor = Color(0xFFDEDDDD)
        )
    )
}`
```

Comment: May be you are using `Material3` libraries and they have changed some parameter name and types.

Comment: makes sense sr, where can I check that?

Comment: I have answered below with explanation you can check it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are using `Material3` libraries and they have changed some parameter name and types. To check it you can check for the imports and dependencies and change according to the requirement:

for **Material 3** this should be

> import androidx.compose.material3.TextField 
> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'

for **Material** this should be

> import androidx.compose.material.TextField 
> implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {},
          keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email))
```

```
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
```

Use normal material

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_ui_version"
```